# Relay access denied (454)

Tags: postfix, email-server, mailman

I have trouble with postfix sending e-mails to any destination (Relay access denied)
And yes, I googled a lot, tried a bunch of things but with no luck. Here is the thing:
I am trying to use Mailman3 as a listserver with Postfix to deliver e-mails to any destination.
If I am requesting access to a list, normally an e-mail is sent to the given e-mail-address. This fails with a 454-error.

```
NOQUEUE: reject: RCPT from localhost[::1]: 454 4.7.1 <receiver@domain.com>: Relay access denied; from=<mailinglist@listserver.com> to=<receiver@domain.com> proto=ESMTP helo=<listserver.domain.com>
```

Here is my main.cf. Stripped down..

```
alias_database = hash:/etc/aliases
alias_maps = hash:/etc/aliases
append_dot_mydomain = no
biff = no
compatibility_level = 2
default_destination_concurrency_limit = 15
default_destination_recipient_limit = 30
header_checks = regexp:/etc/postfix/header_checks
inet_interfaces = all
inet_protocols = all
local_recipient_maps = hash:/var/lib/mailman3/data/postfix_lmtp
mydestination = $myhostname, localhost.$mydomain, localhost.localdomain
myhostname = listserver.domain.com
mynetworks = 127.0.0.0/8
recipient_delimiter = +
smtpd_banner = $myhostname ESMTP $mail_name (Debian/GNU)
transport_maps = hash:/var/lib/mailman3/data/postfix_domains
unknown_local_recipient_reject_code = 550
```

I don't know what's going on. I don't get it. Can someone please enlighten me?

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

It is not totally clear from your question which domain you want to accept emails for. Based on the log you provided I assume it's `domain.com`.

Have you checked `/var/lib/mailman3/data/postfix_domains` file content? Do you have entries for `domain.com` in it?

(The file won't be generated until you added the domain and perhaps a mailing list in Mailman.)